# How to reshape a matrix in Matlab after having vectorized some parts of it?

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a matrix `A` in Matlab

```
m=4;
s=3;
r=2;
A=[1 2;
   3 4; 
   5 6; 
   7 8; 
   9 10; 
  11 12; 
  13 14; 
  15 16; 
  17 18; 
  19 20; 
  21 22; 
  23 24]; %// (m*s) x r
```

and want to obtain the matrix

```
B=[1 7 13 19; 
   3 9 15 21; 
   5 11 17 23; 
   2 8 14 20; 
   4 10 16 22; 
   6 12 18 24];   %// (s*r) x m
```

without using cell (e.g. `mat2cell`).

Comment: I really cant see how you got B. Can you extend a bit on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

```
B = reshape(permute(reshape(A,s,m,[]),[1 3 2]),s*r,[])
```

### Some explanation

There are basically three steps followed in the code listed above and those are listed below for a better understanding of this solution and hopefully must also guide you on your future queries on `reshaping` -

1. With the innermost `reshape`: Cut `A` after every `s` rows and make a `3D` array out of it such that each `3D` slice holds elements of each column of `A`.
2. With the only `permute`: Exchange `dim2` and `dim3`, so that we bring `dim3` elements closer to `dim1` elements as needed for reshaping in the next stage in accordance with the linear indexing used by MATLAB.
3. With the outermost `reshape`: Reshape the elements to bring them to the desired shape (size).

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like

```
cat(1,reshape(A(:,1),3,4),reshape(A(:,2),3,4));
```